# Proxy server with one HTTP and one HTTPS end

Tags: http, https, http-proxy

I'm building a forwarding (http)proxy server that pretty much handles all traffic through HTTPS. My client sends loads of traffic to this server on which it load balances everything among a few proxy addresses. So my client sets up an SSL/TLS connection with my proxy server and he, on his turn does this with the destination server.

Since the connection client--proxy server is internal, the overhead of setting up this SSL/TLS is unnecessary. I was wondering if it would be (theoretically) possible to send my "https://" calls over HTTP to my proxy server, where he would switch to HTTPS over the internet.

Comment: As https and http are working on the application layer and the main difference is that https (i.e. TLS) encrypts/decrypts the messages (before handing/receiving them to/from transport layer) this should not be a big problem. I am just not sure what you mean by sending "your https calls over http". If (as I assume) your client has some (software) clients within the intranet and your proxy is some kind of gateway to the internet you could basically send your request to this gateway as `Client -http-> Gateway -https-> server`. Not sure if stuff like that can already be handled by nginx/apache.

Comment: @Minato What I mean is that my URL's start with "https://", informing the service to set up the HTTPS protocol. That's oke, I'm not using nginx/apache but rather implement my own server engine.